# Haskell function implementing

Tags: function, haskell

I have next data type:

```
newtype Fun i a = F (i -> a)
```

And I have to implement function with next signature:

```
joinFun :: Fun i (Fun i a) -> Fun i a
```

I tried

```
joinFun (F f) = f
```

but it have type `i -> Fun i a`
How can I implement this function with right types?

Comment: Nota bene, it can be derived with [`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/newtype_deriving.html?highlight#extension-GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving): `newtype Fun i a = F (i -> a) deriving newtype (Functor, Applicative, Monad)`

Comment: Having newtypes can seriously hurt the "obviousness" of what goes on, so before you try implementing `Fun i (Fun i a) -> Fun i a` you should implement `(i -> i -> a) -> (i -> a)`. It's the exact same function at runtime but conceptually it is easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f` has as type `i -> Fun i a`, and you are supposed to return a `Fun i a`, so a function that maps an `i` to an `a`.

The only sensical thing to do is construct a function that takes a parameter of type `i`, that will be used on `f`, this will then return a `Fun i a`, where we will evaluate that function by applying it again with that parameter `i`.

We thus can implement `joinFun` with:

```
joinFun :: Fun i (Fun i a) -> Fun i a
joinFun (F f) = F go
    where go i = case f i of
              (F g) -> …
```

where I leave implementing the `…` part as an exercise.